# Scan line of integers in PHP

Tags: php, stdin

I want to scan this 
`3
4 40 90 55 35
3 200 50 0
1 5`

3  is the number of lines 
first number in each row is the number of the following numbers 
and I should get the max and min in each row
here is my code

```
<?php
fscanf(STDIN, "%d", $number);
for ( $i=0 ; $i<$number ; $i++ )
{
    fscanf(STDIN, "%d", $elements);
    $mini = 500;
    $maxi = 0;
    for ( $j=0 ; $j<$elements ; $j++)
    {
        fscanf(STDIN, "%d", $all);
        if ( $mini > $all )
            $mini = $all;
        if ( $maxi < $all )
            $maxi = $all;
    }
    echo $mini;
    echo " ";
    echo $maxi;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

?>

if the input is 
3 
4 
40 
90 
55 
35 
3 
200 
50 
0 
1 
5 
then my code works

Comment: I think this is some coding compettion question like codechef etc ...We don't do it

Comment: no no I am practicing on my own

Comment: it's not a competition question I am trying to improve my skill in PHP and I can't just scan that input in that way

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI  
it's not a competition question I am trying to improve my skill in PHP and I can't just scan that input in that way